# (How) Can I make a Dictionary for variable references?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a lot of functions working basically the same way just using different variables. Short Example:

```
[SyncVar] private Vector3 syncedPlayerPosition;
[SyncVar] private Vector3 syncedHandPosition;

private Transform playerTransform;
private Transform handTransform;

private float lerpPlayerPositionRate;
private float lerpHandPositionRate;

void SetPlayerPosition(){

    if(playerTransform.position != syncedPlayerPosition){
        playerTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(playerTransform.position, syncedPlayerPosition, Time.deltaTime * lerpPlayerPositionRate);
    }
}

void SetHandPosition(){

    if(handTransform.position != syncedHandPosition){
        handTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(handTransform.position, syncedHandPosition, Time.deltaTime * lerpHandPositionRate);
    }
}
```

As you can see both functions do basically exactly the same thing they are just using different Variables.

Now I'm looking for something like this (assuming `Dictionary`s would work like that)

```
[SyncVar] private Vector3 syncedPlayerPosition;
[SyncVar] private Vector3 syncedHandPosition;

private Transform playerTransform;
private Transform handTransform;

private float lerpPlayerPositionRate;
private float lerpHandPositionRate;

/* Add Dictionaries to reference those variables */
private Dictionary<Transform,Vector3> positionDict = new Dictionary<Transform,Vector3>();
private Dictionary<Transform,float> lerpRateDict = new Dictionary<Transform,float>();

private void Start(){
    /* Fill the Dictionaries with Links between the Transforms
     * to the achording variable reference */

    /* Until now not the references are linked but rather values written */
    positionDict.Add(playerTransform, syncedPlayerPosition);
    positionDict.Add(handTransform, syncedHandPosition);

    lerpRateDict.Add(playerTransform, lerpPlayerPositionRate);
    lerpRateDict.Add(handTransform, lerpHandPositionRate);
}

/* Than I could use (and change) only one common function for both e.g like */
void SetPosition(Transform transform){

    if(transform.position != positionDict[transform]){
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, positionDict[transform], Time.deltaTime * lerpRateDict[transform]);
    }

    /* Add this only as example that also this has to be posible */
    lerpRateDict[transform] += 1;
    positionDict[transform] = Vector3.zero(); 
}
```

I actually tried it this way but realized the values in the `Dictionary`s don't get updated but stay whatever they where when `Start()` was called. So it seems to me they are not added to the  `Dictionary`s  by `Reference` but by `Value`.

**Is it possible to set it up in a way so that in Dictionaries actually are not stored the values but rather the references to the existing variables? How can I archieve something like that?**

I have really a lot of those functions and every small change has to be applied to them one-by-one. A setup like I'm looking for would allow me to make those changes only once for all.

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that: Within those functions sometimes also hte `Vector3` and `float` values might get changed not only the `Transform`s.

Comment: Store non-value types but reference types instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster How?

Comment: By wrapping it in a `ValueTypeContainer<T>` you create or something like that.

Comment: Sorry I don't really get it .. can you give me a short example? What would be a reference type for this scenario?

Comment: you don't need dictionary for this, A simple method would be enough to achieve what you want. Check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create a method which can be called for all of your transforms:

```
void SyncPositions(Transform thisTransform, Vector3 targetPosion, float rate)
{
    if (thisTransform.position != targetPosion)
    {
        thisTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(thisTransform.position, targetPosion, Time.deltaTime * rate);
    }
}
```

You can call this for player transform or hand transform.

```
SyncPosition(playerTransform,syncedPlayerPosition,lerpPlayerPositionRate);
SyncPosition(handTransform,syncedHandPosition,lerpHandPositionRate);
```

hope this helps

Comment: This would make so much more sense that a freaky dictionary concept. The name tells the action, the parameters tell the actors. Simple.

Comment: Hi sorry this is not enough. I didn't mention that but within those functions also the `Vector3` and `float` values might get changed .. this wouldn't be possible with this approach.

Comment: @derHugo Do you want to alter the values passed as parameters in SetPosition() ?

Comment: @UmairM Yes this might be maybe a startpoint. I editted my question a bit so you can see I also want to set those values sometimes.

Comment: Use ref or out keyword. Those are working like pointer to the values and allow to change them within the method while affecting the original passed as parameter. Do not consider boxing there. Stick to what is working best, boxing is slow.

Comment: @UmairM thanks a lot I guess this might save me a lot of trouble. I'm trying it now with function and e.g. `ref float lerpRate`.